# Use of DQS APIs

Tags: c#, master-data-services

**Requirement:**
We have created DQS Knowledgebase, Domains, Domain Values/Rules using DQS client provided by SQL.
Now, we need to invoke DQM Knowledgebase, domain values , Rules from .Net application using an API. User should be able to provide input values and select the Domain, Value/Rule. User should get corrected Output value with attributes such as confidence level on operation execution
We are able to achieve this using SSIS but we are looking for APIs which can be used in ASP .net client application.
Approach: So far Approach we have taken is, configure Master Data Manager web service, this allows programmatic use of the features of Master Data Service (DQS can be integrated with Master data service).
This WCF service have set of Data Quality Service Operations such as DataQualityCleansingOperationCreate, DataQualityKnowledgeBasesGet, DataQualityMatchingOperationCreate, DataQualityOperationStart, DataQualityOperationResultsGet.
Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh230995.aspx

**Problem:**
we are not able identify the exact implementation sequence of these operations. We are trying to find out,
How we can provide Input values to these operations, How to select the Operation to perform, How to associate Domain, values, rules, references to operation. How to read the result object.
Any help/pointers or alternative approach are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Om

Comment: Not supported and not available are sometimes to distinctly different things. I appreciate this question. And here's an implementation of the API https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=domainvalueimport. Folks, stop down voting legitimate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot programmatically use/access DQS functionality because its not supported in the current version of DQS.

This fact that DQS will not provide any public APIs in SQL Server 2012 is clearly documented in Q.12 of DQS FAQs on the TechNet Wiki: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3919.data-quality-services-dqs-faq.aspx#Q_12_Will_DQS_provide_public_APIs.

Thanks,

Vivek

Comment: SSIS has a dataflow component to talk to DQS though...I wonder how that works